# How to create multiselect to show detail of each selected in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

[Description Image Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRiOn.png)

I want to create a small demo like the picture if I click the item in the left column to choose the Country and the right column will display all the city of country in the left column that I chosen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small sample, I hope it helps you:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <style>
         select {
         min-width: 100px;
         float: left;
         margin-right: 20px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <select id="countrySelect" size="10"></select>
      <select id="citySelect"  size="10"></select>
      <script>
         var countries = [{name: "USA", id:1}, {name: "Canada", id:2}];             
         var cities = [{name: "New York", id:1, countryId:1}, {name: "Boston", id:2, countryId:1}, {name: "Ottawa", id:3, countryId:2}, {name: "Toronto", id:4, countryId:2}];

         var $countrySelect = $('#countrySelect');
         var $citySelect = $('#citySelect'), countrySelectHtml = '';
         for (var i=0; i<countries.length; i++) $countrySelect.append($('<option>').attr('value', countries[i].id).text(countries[i].name));

         $countrySelect.change(function () {
            var countryId = $countrySelect.val();
            $citySelect.html('');
            for (var i=0; i<cities.length; i++) 
                if (cities[i].countryId == countryId) $citySelect.append($('<option />').attr('value', cities[i].id).text(cities[i].name));
         });

         $citySelect.change(function () {
            alert('Selected city: ' + $(this).find('option:selected').text() + ' (id=' + $citySelect.val() + ')');
         });

      </script>
</html>
```